# Does an advanced Dialogue state tracking eliminate the need of intent classifier and slot filling models in dialogue systems/ chatbots?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, chat-bots

I am learning to create a dialogue system. The various parts of such a system are Intent classifier, slot filling, Dialogue state tracking (DST), dialogue policy optimization and NLG.

While reading [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/44018.pdf) paper on DST, I found out that a discriminative  sequence model of DST can identify goal constraints, fill slots and maintain state of the conversation.

Does this mean that now I dont need to create an intent classifier and slot filling models separately as the tasks are already being done by this DST? Or I am misunderstanding both the things and they are separate?